# How can I collect packets on 5165 MHz frequency?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debian, kali-linux

I have an Intel AX210 Wifi 6E supported wireless card.
There is a device that broadcasts WIFI on the 5165 MHz frequency.
For my cyber security research, I need to collect packets from this device broadcasting on the 5165 MHz frequency.

Even though I set various countries on my network card, I couldn't do it. How can I do it?

---

**Update**: The guy in this [Github](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng/issues/2205) repo was able to see the frequency I wanted using Intel AX210. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What do you see exactly? Which Debian release?

Comment: WiFi 6E is hardware region locked.  This means unavailable channels will NOT be offered in a given region.  Is this specific channel allowed by your region?

Comment: Did you mean the single 20MHz-wide channel, called channel# 32, whose center frequency is at 5160 MHz? Support for that channel seems rare. I don't know why anyone would expect to find "33 channels" at 5165 MHz, because in Wi-Fi 5GHz channel naming conventions, there isn't really a single channel named 33 at 5165MHz, much less 33 different channels all packed in there. Can you link to the source of information that gave you this expectation?

Comment: I updated my problem.

Comment: Can you explain why you think changing countries/regions on your WiFi card would enable this? Are you trying to select countries that include that frequency in their WiFi spectrum? Does the "Default" region of your WiFi device not include this frequency? Do you know that your WiFi device can be set to "promiscuous" or "monitoring" mode? Relevant: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3774/using-wireless-cards-in-promiscuous-mode

Comment: Firstly, if you mean 5.165 GHz then say that. Secondly, 5150 – 5925 is band 46 of LTE, not wi-fi. Are you trying to sniff LTE traffic?

Comment: @Spiff: To be fair, I've had a few kinds of readily available equipment that's able to use both "out of range" channels and "5 MHz offset" channels and other weird combinations. Mikrotik consumer hardware often has the capability if set to superchannel' mode (except for the FCC-locked USA version) – e.g. my hAP ac2 has a range of 4920-5925 MHz.

Comment: @u1686_grawity That may be the key to what OP needs. Mikrotik exposes nonstandard channel arrangements that the vast majority of vendors and products don't support, and according to one Mikrotik help document I saw, only their hardware that uses the Atheros 92xx chipset supports these nonstandard channels. So maybe OP needs an Atheros 92xx card (probably with a flexible driver on Linux) or a Mikrotik product with an Atheros 92xx chipset, in order to use the very nonstandard 5165 MHz center frequency.